# Trying to log into site using python

Tags: python

i am a novice at web scraping but would like to try use it in a project. I want to log into a fantasyfootball site, below is the form from the website:

```
<fieldset>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="695" class="data-entry">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><span>Email Address</span></label>
                <input id="j_username" class="required email" type="text" name="j_username" title="*Please enter a valid email address" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label><span>Password</span></label>
                <input id="j_password" class="required password" type="password" name="j_password" title="*Please enter a valid password<br/>(minimum 6 characters)" />
```

And here is my code so far:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from urllib.parse import urlencode
url='https://users.premierleague.com/PremierUser/account/login.html'
h=Http()
email='myemail'
password='mypassword'
h.add_credentials(email,password)
data={'j_username':'myemail','j_password':'mypassword'}
web_data = urlencode(data)
response, content = h.request(url, 'POST', web_data)
```

I am not getting any errors, just nothing at all

Comment: I shall advice the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Comment: Could  you `print response`?

Comment: Are you sure you've got all the packets? You can dissect a request sent by using the Chrome developer tools to check this.

Comment: this is the response:content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'content-language': 'en-GB', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'date': 'Wed, 29 Oct 2014 14:23:24 GMT', 'status': '200', 'connection': 'close', 'set-cookie': 'BIGipServerPOOL-46.38.180.105-8443=3407089836.64288.0000; path=/'}

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way to log in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are POST'ing to the page containing the login form, not the page that processes the login form.  If you inspect the HTML for the login form, you will see that the `action` url is "../j_spring_security_check" which equates to https://users.premierleague.com/PremierUser/j_spring_security_check.  So in your code change the URL to that.  Also get rid of the `add_credentials` line because they're not using HTTP Basic Auth.  Once you get this far you probably still won't get a body back in the response from the login page.  On successful login, it will probably 302 you to the homepage.  So look carefully at your response headers as you're doing this.  Also on successful login it's going to give you some sort of session ID which you will need to include in subsequent requests to prove that you're logged in.  The details of that will be specific to however this site manages sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. i changed it around and still nothing happens.i got a different response though:{'content-length': '0', 'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8', 'location': 'https://users.premierleague.com/PremierUser/account/login-retry.html', 'set-cookie': 'BIGipServerPOOL-46.38.180.105-8443=3373535404.64288.0000; path=/', 'date': 'Wed, 29 Oct 2014 14:37:42 GMT', 'status': '302', 'connection': 'close'}

Comment: OK so it's saying your credentials are invalid, notice how it's redirecting you to the login-retry page.

Comment: yea i noticed it was sending me back to the retry-login page, the credentials are correct. I am just trying to change around a few bits to see if anything works, coming up short